# WPF Problem handling right-to-left TextBox with percent character

Tags: c#, wpf, right-to-left

I think there is a problem with WPF and right to left input when it comes to handling the percent sign (might also apply to similar signs).

When the TextBox is Right-to-Left oriented and there is no Hebrew characters at the start of the text, the percent sign is rendered on the wrong side of the number.

You can see the abnormal behaviour in this video:

[image: Demonstration Screen Capture]

Here is my application XAML (As you can see there is nothing in it):

```
<Window x:Class="HebrewTextTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Margin="10">
        <TextBox Text=" 25% הנחה"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Any idea if there is a solution for this?

Note that I do not have any control on the text, since the user types it in...

Answer (score 1):

On textbox text changed event add the right to left mark to the text:

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" Text=" 25% הנחה" TextChanged="Textbox1_TextChanged"/>

bool addRtlMark = false;
private void Textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
 if (!addRtlMark)
  {
    addRtlMark = true;
    textBox1.Text = "\u200f" + textBox1.Text.Replace("\u200f", "");
    addRtlMark  = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would put it to a behavior for it can be reused in XAML for any `TextBox`

Comment: But this mark will be inserted into the database too if the TextBox is binded...
Also, what is the usage of the 'wrapTextWithRtlMark' variable?

Comment: @NirKornfeld about the mark you have to remove it if you do not want it stored in the DB. "wrapTextWithRtlMark" i did a correction please check it.